# How to access individual elements of user defined data types?

Tags: postgresql

This is a Postgres SQL question.

I am having a user defined data type as follows.

`create type my_type as (name varchar(100), credit_points double precision)`

I am having a table which uses the above type as column's datatype as below.

```
create table tab1 (
    id serial,
    name_credit my_type
)
```

I could insert values into this table using below insert statement.

```
insert into tab1 (name_credit) values(('santhosh', 101.75)::my_type)
```

Now, I want to access the table like below.

```
select * from tab1 where name_credit[2] between 100.0 and 110.0
```

or

```
select * from tab1 where name_credit.credit_points between 100.0 and 110.0
```

But neither of it is working for me. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the column name in `()`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM tab1
       WHERE (name_credit).credit_points BETWEEN 100.0
                                                 AND 110.0;
```

See ["8.16.3. Accessing Composite Types"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING) for more details.